# Why does an extra "-" character show up in my output?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I'm trying to create a yahoo messenger autoreply application.I can retrieve the new message if I use a button to retrieve it,but If I use timer to get new message, it shows me new message with and extra mark. This is the error.

[image: Error]

And this is the code:

```
Private Sub Pause(ByVal seconds As Integer)
    Dim current As Date

    current = DateTime.Now
    Do While (DateTime.Now - current).TotalSeconds < seconds
        Application.DoEvents()
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
    Loop
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Dim keyword As String = ""
    Dim arrKeyword() As String
    Dim param As String = ""

    ymVersion = getYMVersion()
    Select Case ymVersion
        Case "8"
        hwndYMMainClass = FindWindow("YSearchMenuWndClass", vbNullString)
        Case "9"
            hwndYMMainClass = FindWindow("ATL:007C07F0", vbNullString)
        Case "10"
            hwndYMMainClass = FindWindow("CConvWndBase", vbNullString)
    End Select

    If hwndYMMainClass <> 0 Then
        pause(1)
        ymid = getYMID(hwndYMMainClass)
        msg = getYMMessage(hwndYMMainClass)
        lstBox.Items.Add(ymid + "-" + msg)
        ymChatSend(hwndYMMainClass, "Telah terima")
        closeYM(hwndYMMainClass)
    End If
End Sub
```

By the way I use a timer with the interval of 500.where is the mistake that shows an extra -  than it should be?thanks

Comment: When you refer to "an extra mark" what exactly do you mean?

Comment: Does your button event handler and the timer elapsed code use the EXACT SAME code? Because I see this in your code via pastebin `lstBox.Items.Add(ymid + "-" + msg)` and is _that_ the extra `-` mark you're speaking of?

Comment: @Intrus an -,I think my words are wrong,sorry for my bad english an I don't know how to say it properly.in my code I use lstbox.add.item(ymid+"-"+msg),when I run the application,after I receive new message with that format,it add an extra - ,like in the image I attach.Thanks

Comment: @hometoast yes,it is.the extra - is what I mean,and yes that the button event handler is the the same with the timer code.

Comment: That use of Pause() is evil. Using DoEvents() is suspect in the first place, but during a timer_tick event is especially problematic.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is your Pauses(). Any use of DoEvents() is always suspect, but here you do it during a timer tick event, and that's especially problematic — you're lucky not to be seeing StackOverflow Exceptions.

Here's what's happening: When you call Pause(), the program enters a loop to alternately sleep and handle other events. If there is another event to handle, it's just like calling that method directly on the current execution path. Since you have a timer that is periodically placing new events in the message queue, your timer tick handler can indirectly end up as a recursive function and call itself. If you're not careful you can find that this happens faster than the events are completed: the tick handler runs, which calls Pause(), Pause() calls DoEvents(), and DoEvents() calls the tick handler again, over and over. The code to close Yahoo is never reached, and you end up adding to your call stack until it is full (overflows) and the program crashes.

Thankfully, that's not happening here. The symptoms suggest that your tick method does recurse on itself, but it only recurs exactly once. The event fires, it reaches the call to DoEvents(), which runs the tick event again in the same execution path. This time the event processes all the way through (Pause() completes before another tick event is raised) and does everything it's supposed to. Now the original event can finish processing, only there's no message to read any more. It is left to concatenate two empty strings with the "-" character, and **there's your extra output.**

Personally, I'd re-write to avoid using DoEvents(), but *for a quick fix here try disabling your timer on the first line of the tick event and re-enabling it on the last line of the tick event.*

Comment: Good answer Joel, i realized this too late ;)

Comment: @Joel Coehoom what is your suggestion and if I have to rewrite it,what should I learn to rewrite it?thanks

Comment: @yonghan79 read the last part of my last sentence (now in italics!) for an easy fix. To rewrite it, try using a BackgroundWorker control, which will let you call sleep() directly without worrying about blocking on the main thread. You still might want to disable the timer, but perhaps only if you actually enter the If block where you need to sleep.

Comment: @Joel Coehoorn I have tried to disable the timer on the first line and re-enabling it it on the laste line,the application doesn't work as it should be. [Code](http://pastebin.com/8pPvtst5)

Answer (score 1):

> I realized it too late! ;-) , the problem is due to the listbox.items.add() executing twice because of
>   "System.DoEvents()"

What i would recommend is the following changes in your code, please advise if they fix your issue.

**From this:**

```
 ymid = getYMID(hwndYMMainClass)
 msg = getYMMessage(hwndYMMainClass)
 lstBox.Items.Add(ymid + "-" + msg)
```

**To This:**

```
 ymid = getYMID(hwndYMMainClass)
 msg = getYMMessage(hwndYMMainClass)
 lstBox.Items.Add(cstr(ymid) & "-" & cstr(msg))
```

If that does not fix your problem, i'm pretty sure whatever comes in as a message has a trailing "-" at the end, if every single list entry you get ends up with an additional line of "-" then try to use the following to eliminate the last character if it does indeed find a "-".

**Remove the trailing "-" from the msg:**

```
Dim holdMsg as String = vbnullstring 'I'm not sure if msg is of type String...

     ymid = getYMID(hwndYMMainClass)
     msg = getYMMessage(hwndYMMainClass)
     holdMsg = cstr(msg)

        If holdMsg.Last = "-" Then
            'Remove that char from the string
            holdMsg = holdMsg.Substring(0, holdMsg.Length - 1)
            lstBox.Items.Add(cstr(ymid) & "-" & holdMsg)
        End If
```

Comment: I will try it and I will tell you if it works,does it probaly caused by the timer or the pause function that cause it to call the tick function twice?thanks.

Comment: cstr() has nothing to do with it.